# Raspberry Pi 5GHz Dongle

Tags: wifi

I would like to ask if anyone has used a Raspberry Pi 5GHz dongle that works easily?

Comment: Have you checked this list http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters

Comment: yes I have, but it isn't very straight forward, and some of those devices are hard to obtain in the US. was wondering if anyone else has had success out of the box

Comment: possible duplicate of [5 Ghz Wifi on Raspberry Pi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22194/5-ghz-wifi-on-raspberry-pi)